# stacked bar chart in JQPlot not showing label for few stack bars

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am generating stacked bar chart using JQplot where values are in decimal numbers. I am not getting stack label for first stack bars. I have attached my code and screen shoot. please let me know the mistake I am doing .

```
var s1 = [69.44,48.70,70.00,70.00,70.00,70.00,70.00,67.35];
        var s2 = [0.00,0.00,27.08,25.04,12.47,26.80,11.83,0.00];
        var ticks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H'];
         plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2], {
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
          fillToZero: true, barDirection: 'horizontal'
      },
      pointLabels: {show: true,hideZeros:true,}
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
           pad: 1.05,
           tickOptions: {formatString: '%.2f %'},
      },
      yaxis: {
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
         ticks: ticks
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      location: 'e',
      placement: 'outside'
    }     
  });
```

[image]

Comment: `enter code here` part is garbage, please remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jqPlot and can't make your example work, but the problem is that the labels are drawn inside the `s2` series. s2 values for A, B and H all equal 0.00, so there is no graph drawn and nowhere to place the label.

Either place the label outside the bars, inside `s1`, og make sure no values are 0.00.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue have been fixed . I have used tickInterval for x-axis to solve it.

Here is the code :

```
    s1 = [69.44,48.70,70.00,70.00,70.00,70.00,70.00,67.35];

    s2 = [0.00,0.00,27.08,25.04,12.47,26.80,11.83,0.00];

    ticks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H'];
     plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [s1, s2], {
stackSeries: true,
captureRightClick: true,
seriesDefaults:{
  renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
  rendererOptions: {
      fillToZero: true, barDirection: 'horizontal'
  },
  pointLabels: {show: true,hideZeros:true,labelsFromSeries:true,xpadding: 6}
},
axes: {
  xaxis: {
       pad: 1.05,
       tickOptions: {formatString: '%.2f %'},
       min:0.00,
       tickInterval : 10.00,
       max:100.00,
  },
  yaxis: {
     renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
     ticks: ticks,
  }
},
legend: {
  show: true,
  location: 'e',
  placement: 'outside'
}
```

});